# How to impute missing values with row mean in R

Tags: r, na

From a large data frame, I have extracted a row of numeric data and saved as a vector. Some of the values are missing and marked as NA. I want to impute the missing values with row mean.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let `x` be your vector:

```
x <- c(NA,0,2,0,2,NA,NA,NA,0,2)
ifelse(is.na(x), mean(x, na.rm = TRUE), x)
# [1] 1 0 2 0 2 1 1 1 0 2
```

Or if you don't care for the original vector, you can modify it directly:

```
x[is.na(x)] <- mean(x, na.rm = TRUE)
```

Comment: My vector is as follows after I converted into numeric using as.numeric: [1]    NA    NA    NA -0.58  0.23 -0.23  0.08 -0.62  0.55 -0.32  0.03 -0.56
[13]  0.47 -0.15  0.49    NA  0.23 -0.49  0.33  0.18  0.65 -0.29    NA    NA
After running through your code sample I am getting the following: [1]  3.857953e-18  3.857953e-18  3.857953e-18 -5.800000e-01  2.300000e-01
 [6] -2.300000e-01  8.000000e-02 -6.200000e-01  5.500000e-01 -3.200000e-01
<more characters left out by me to fit here>

Comment: I tried to convert the output to numeric, but didn't work. Thanks

Comment: and what is the problem? Is it that you are getting numbers in scientific notation?

Comment: Yes, I want to convert into numeric. Thanks

Comment: It is already numeric (see `is.numeric(x)` but printed in scientific notation due to the floating point errors from the mean. If you want to loose some of the floating point errors so "it prints nicely", you can do something like `round(x * 1e5) / 1e5`...

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
filter <- is.na(myVec)

myVec[filter] <- colMeans(myDF[,filter], na.rm=TRUE)
```

Where `myVec` is your vector and `myDF` is your data.frame.

Comment: I don't want to use the myDF. Is it possible to replace the missing value in the row itself, just using myVec?

Comment: @user466663, hence the need to sort out what is relevant from what is not when writing a question. You should have started with "I have a vector..."

Comment: @flodel, indeed, you've successfully managed to read both the OP mind and mine. Thanks!